# If a game makes someone anxious, how do you explain that game

Tags: single-word-requests

For example;

The feedback form on a game says, "Please rate your experience of the game"

And uses the following words:

- Not fun at all - Very fun
- Not boring at all - Very boring
- Not challenging at all - Very challenging
- Not frustrating at all - Very frustrating
- Not exciting at all - Very exciting
- **Not anxious at all - Very anxious**

Now the last item, describes how you feel when you play the game, not the game itself. The game is not anxious.

So, if the game "makes her feel bored" you could describe the game as "boring".

So if the game "makes him feel anxious", how would you describe the game? What word would imply it makes people feel anxious?

Comment: Ignoring the first one *fun* about which the least said the better (yuk), all the others besides anxious are verbs. *Anxious* is an adverb, and therein lies your problem - it does not have a present participle.  There are a number of other words you could use - if you do a thesaurus search - and the one I prefer, I think, is *perturbing*.

Comment: Within the context of the gaming-industry jargon, I would use _intense_.

Comment: That sounds like an answer I would upvote, @bradimus!

Answer (score 3):

They could use ***[distressing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/distressing)***.  Distress isn't exactly the same as anxiety but it's pretty close, and in this context might be identical.

Answer (score 1):

What about ***[disquieting](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disquieting):***

> - causing mental discomfort; "the disquieting sounds of nearby gunfire"

(The Free Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Within the context of the gaming-industry jargon, I would use *intense*.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest using [stressful](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stressful) (adj.), derived from [stress](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stress#stress__2) (noun):

Defn. 2: a state of mental or emotional strain or tension resulting from adverse or demanding circumstances

Source:  [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

Answer (score 0):

How about *nerve-racking*?

M-W:

> [*nerve-racking*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nerve-racking):
> causing a person to feel very nervous
>
> [*anxious*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anxious): afraid
> or nervous especially about what may happen : feeling anxiety;
> characterized by extreme uneasiness of mind or brooding fear about
> some contingency

Something that is *nerve-racking* is something that *causes* anxiety, not anxiety itself. So, you could change "Not anxious at all - Very anxious" to "Not *nerve-racking* at all - Very *nerve-racking*.

*Nerve-racking* addresses your question while preserving the sense of anxiety or anxiousness in the original feedback form.